# Path is not found after joining

Tags: python, path, escaping

I have made a function for downloading images to a specific folder

```py
def get_images(folder_path):
    for urls in list_of_urls:
        for url in urls:
            response = requests.get(url)

            # Extract the file name from the URL
            file_name = url.split('/')[-1]

            # Construct the file path
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)

            # Save the image file
            with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(response.content)
    

    #specify the folder path to save the images to
    folder_path = "D:\Lokale schijf\companyname\datafiles\BRANDS\VDV\images\FW2023\20230711test"
    
    #call the function get_images
    get_images(folder_path)
```

when I execute the code it results in an error code

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16580/2387954813.py in <module>
     22 
     23 #call the function get_images
---> 24 get_images(folder_path)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16580/2387954813.py in get_images(folder_path)
     14 
     15             # Save the image file
---> 16             with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
     17                 file.write(response.content)
     18 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Lokale schijf\\companyname\\datafiles\\BRANDS\\VDV\\images\\FW2023\x8230711test\\primadonna-lingerie-underwired_bra-deauville-0161811-black-0_3456144.jpg'
```

all requested images files are saved in a folder with the given folder_path. Why the error?

Comment: FYI: Nowadays (since Python 3.4), you would use the power of [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of using `os.path.join`. Additionally: You could use slashes instead of backslashes. Yes, that also works on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Likely solution use a raw string prepended with an `r`

```
r"D:\Lokale schijf\companyname\datafiles\BRANDS\VDV\images\FW2023\20230711test"
```

If you compare your path with the error you will see that `\\FW2023\x8230711test\\` is different `\20` is interpreted different in an unescaped string messing up your path and gives a directory order that does not exist on your system which leads to the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
"D:/Lokale schijf/companyname/datafiles/BRANDS/VDV/images/FW2023/20230711test"
```

OR

```
"D:\\Lokale schijf\\companyname\\datafiles\\BRANDS\\VDV\\images\\FW2023\\20230711test"
```

OR

```
r"D:\Lokale schijf\companyname\datafiles\BRANDS\VDV\images\FW2023\20230711test"
```

OR

```
os.path.join("D:", "Lokale schijf", "companyname", "datafiles", "BRANDS", "VDV", "images", "FW2023", "20230711test")
```